# Why AIML pattern matching is not working?

Tags: python, chatbot, aiml

I'm working on a voice bot, which will get user voice input and executes task based on it. I'm using AIML 1.0. The problem I'm facing is that the pattern matching is not working.

```
<category>
    <pattern>OPEN SAP</pattern>
    <template>
         <random>
           <li>Sure thing!</li>
           <li>Right away, sir!</li>
           <li>On it!</li>
        </random>
        <system>start saplogon </system>
    </template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>* OPEN SAP</pattern>
    <srai> OPEN SAP </srai>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>* SAP *</pattern>
    <srai> OPEN SAP </srai>
</category>
```

When I say 'Can you open SAP', it is not recognizing. What is the problem in the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replicated and identified your issue. You forgot to include `<template>` tag.

Here is the correct AIML for your case:

```
<category>
    <pattern>OPEN SAP</pattern>
    <template>
        <random>
            <li>Sure thing!</li>
            <li>Right away, sir!</li>
            <li>On it!</li>
        </random>
        <system>start saplogon </system>
    </template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>* OPEN SAP</pattern>
    <template>
        <srai> OPEN SAP </srai>
    </template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>* SAP *</pattern>
    <template>
        <srai> OPEN SAP </srai>
    </template>
</category>
```

It will work as expected now.
Hope it helps.

Comment: All are aiml files. I can't find those .brn files. What might me the problem?

Comment: Ya sure. Should i post it somewhere and post the link here?

Comment: @Sid add that in your question details.

Comment: Haha. Done bro.